# Converting a CSV File Into a 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i convert the data inside an CSV file to a 2d array?

```
array[row][column]
```

I already have an upload script that will display all the data inside a CSV file.

Little snippet of my code, here's the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/Meesz/wj6q7c30/

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cells = rows[i].split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = cells[j];
    }
  }
  var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
  dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
  dvCSV.appendChild(table);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Real answer: Use [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/) . Save yourself the hassle of escaped/quoted fields, fields with delimiters in them, variations in the CSV format, etc...

The "do it yourself" way: `csvStr.split("\n").map(function(row){return row.split(",");})`

Comment: The DIY way is a bad idea. Use a real parser.

Comment: Agreed. You can only lead a horse to water though

Comment: You should use return in the map function.

Answer (score 8):

### Use `String.split()` and `Array.map()`

Because "the `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array" *(source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))*, it is <del>ideally suited</del> *somewhat suitable* for creating a two dimensional array from a *very basic* CSV string that has already been converted into an array via the `split()` method.

```js
function csvToArray (csv) {
    rows = csv.split("\n");

    return rows.map(function (row) {
     return row.split(",");
    });
};

// Hard-coded for brevity, but you can set this variable with FileReader
var csv = "the,quick,brown,fox\n" +
          "jumps,over,the,lazy,dog";

var array = csvToArray(csv);

console.log(array);
```

```html
Open your console.
```

**Update:**

This basic solution falls apart if your cells contain quotes, commas or other escaped characters. To address more complex CSV strings, you'd have to implement a RegEx solution (see accepted answer to [How can I parse a CSV string with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript)); and to support multiple common formats, you'd be better off just using a library.

Comment: What if the row is `"Hello, how are you","Smith,John",34`?

Comment: Touché. You'd have to implement a RegEx test within the `map()` callback. And then it can get hairier from there.

Answer (score 3):

I needed something like this today so I found snippet originally done by by Bennadel and cleaned it up a bit also adding in edge cases.

```
/*
 *  shortened version of:
 *   http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-ask-ben-parsing-csv-strings-with-javascript-exec-regular-expression-command.htm
 *
 *  Supports columns that are quoted/non-quoted. Takes care of quoted columns that may also have \n's inside
 *  them instead of using a naive approach of split('\n')
 *
 *  @param csvString {string} CSV file of rows separated by new lines.  
 *  @param delimiter {string} delimiter used to split columns 
 *
 *  return {rows} Array of rows with columns containing parsed CSV data
 */

function CSVParse(csvString, delimiter = ",") {

  if (!csvString || !csvString.length)
    return [];

  const pattern = new RegExp(
   ( "(\\" + delimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +
     "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +
     "([^\"\\" + delimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
   ), "gi"
  );

  let rows = [[]]; 
  let matches = false;

  while (matches = pattern.exec(csvString)) {

    const matched_delimiter = matches[1];
    const matched_cellQuote = matches[2];
    const matched_cellNoQuote = matches[3];

    /*
     * Edge case: Data that starts with a delimiter
     */
    if (matches.index == 0 && matched_delimiter)
      rows[rows.length - 1].push("");

    /*
     * Fix empty lines
     */
    if(!matches[2] && !matches[3])
      continue;

    if (matched_delimiter.length && matched_delimiter !== delimiter)
      rows.push([]);

    const matched_value = (matched_cellQuote)
      ? matched_cellQuote.replace(
          new RegExp("\"\"", "g"), "\""
        )
      : matched_cellNoQuote;

    rows[rows.length - 1].push(matched_value);

   }

   return rows;
}
```

Comment: fantastic. any drawbacks?

Comment: I think the only possible drawback is the accuracy of the regex.  I needed a vanilla JS CSV parser to use in Google AppScript and I really didn't want to use a third party parser if possible.  This is doing the job perfectly so far during testing: if I find any exceptions I'll just tweak the regex to cover anything that comes up.  Looks solid so far though.

Comment: Just found an error that it won't parse `,,` (double comma) as a blank cell, the cell is removed altogther.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is similar to (but simpler than) what you're already doing to display the results:

```
var data = [];
var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var cells = rows[i].split(",");
  data.push( cells );
}
```

```js
var data = [];
var csv = "one,two,three\n" +
          "four,five,six";

var rows = csv.split("\n");

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var cells = rows[i].split(",");
  data.push( cells );
}

console.dir(data);
```

Comment: But how can i select one row and a column like here in JSP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034833/converting-csv-file-into-2d-array/33035276?noredirect=1#comment53894097_33035276

Comment: Just like you'd think: `data[1][2]` would be the third column in the second row.

Comment: What if the row is `"Hello, how are you","Smith,John",34`?

Comment: Then see Fabio's answer, and get a real CSV parser.

Comment: Then declare `data` outside the function, populate it in the function, and use it wherever you like.