# Fetching data from a CSV file and storing it into a 2D array - Java

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array, static-block

I have a csv file saved with the name - "public/csvFiles/pushup.csv", where I have converted a 2D matrix into csv format.
Now I want to make a static method in a manager class, where in I will make a 2D array by fetching data from that csv file.
So I want to know how to do that. How to make a 2D array from the data present in the csv file?

I have made my csv file in the following format :

- comma separated values, after every comma, means new column
- every new line means new row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting CSV File Into 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034833/converting-csv-file-into-2d-array)

Comment: Use a CSV parser library, like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]). Also show some **research effort** before posting a question, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If I get you right - the first dimension of an array is structure reflecting lines.
Second dimension - rows of CSV file.

So I propose to create a structure reflecting row.
Names must be meaningful.
But the idea is:

```
RowClss {
    String row;
    String row 2;
    // etc
}
```

Then in the loop, you can read the file and fill the array:

```
String[x][y] rows = new String[x][y];

for(ont i = 0; i < file.size; i++) {
    // read line from file and parse it here
    for(j = 0; j < numOfColumns;j++) {
        rows[j][i] = new String(valueOfCurrentCollumn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use comments to ask for clarifications. Until you have high enough reputation, focus on questions you can answer without asking for clarification.

Comment: Thank you. Get it.